# why module exports not working in javascript?

Tags: javascript, export, javascript-objects

I want to use `module.exports` to move User to another folder, but it is not working

The console give this error

> script.js:542 Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined

```
class User {
  constructor(name, email) {
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
  }
  courseList = [];
  getInfo() {
    return {
      name: this.name,
      email: this.email
    };
  }

  enrollCourse(name) {
    this.courseList.push(name);
  }
  getCourseList() {
    return this.courseList;
  }
}

module.exports= User;
```

This in the new folder

```
import User from "./script";

const piyush = new User("piyush", "piyush@gmail.com");

console.log(piyush);
```

Comment: Did you mean `module.exports = User` instead? Also is this for node, or the browser?

Comment: You're mixing JavaScript module syntax with CommonJS.

Answer (score 0):

It is wrong way to export **module.exports.User** change this to this **module.exports = Users;** and assign your class to this Users variable.
after that require it in the file where you want to use it.
**final code**

```
var Users = class User {
  constructor(name, email) {
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
  }
  courseList = [];
  getInfo() {
    return {
      name: this.name,
      email: this.email
    };
  }

  enrollCourse(name) {
    this.courseList.push(name); // in console this will as show as undefine because you not using return
    // return this.courseList.push(name); // if you use return then this will show 1 means items get added in your array.
  }
  getCourseList() {
    return this.courseList;
  }
}

module.exports = Users;
```

this is for new folder

```
var Users = require("./javascript.js");

const piyush = new Users("piyush", "piyush@gmail.com");
console.log(piyush); // get constructor from your json.
console.log(piyush.getInfo()); // get getInfo from your json.
console.log(piyush.enrollCourse("cse")); // get enrollCourse from your json.
console.log(piyush.getCourseList()); // get getCourseList from your json.
```

Comment: thank you very much for effort. but  i've also using this module.exports= User;  but this also did not work. chrome showed paushed debugger and say module is not defined

Comment: maybe this link will be able to help. https://hashnode.com/post/module-not-defined-as-an-error-in-javascript-cjf5sq8tm00zpy5s213knebuc

Comment: @piyush_raj it won't work in chrome, because chrome doesn't support require/module exports.